# App startup screen routing using react-native-navigation package

Tags: javascript, xcode, meteor, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app w/Meteor and have been trying out a few npm packages to determine which can best handle both native tabbed and drawer navigation. The `react-native-navigation` package seems to do a really great job - but it seems to be bypassing the logic I had been using to determine the user logged in state on startup.

Here's the App.js file, which is imported into both the Android and iOS index files on load:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Meteor, { createContainer } from 'react-native-meteor';

import LoggedOut from './layouts/LoggedOut';
import LoggedIn from './layouts/LoggedIn';
import Loading from './components/Loading';
import config from './config';

Meteor.connect(config.METEOR_URL);

const MyApp = (props) => {
  const { status, user, loggingIn } = props;

  if (status.connected === false || loggingIn) {
    return <Loading />;
  } else if (user !== null) {
    return <LoggedIn />;
  } else {
    return <LoggedOut />;
  }
};

MyApp.propTypes = {
  status: React.PropTypes.object,
  user: React.PropTypes.object,
  loggingIn: React.PropTypes.bool,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  return {
    status: Meteor.status(),
    user: Meteor.user(),
    loggingIn: Meteor.loggingIn(),
  };
}, MyApp);
```

And I've placed the react-native-navigation `Navigation.startTabBasedApp()` code in the `<LoggedIn/>` Component as such:

```js
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

import { registerScreens } from '../helpers/navigation';
registerScreens();

Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
  tabs: [
    {
      label: 'Records',
      screen: 'screen.Records',
      icon: require('../images/NavigatorMenuIcon1.png'),
      selectedIcon: require('../images/NavigatorMenuIcon1.png'),
      title: 'Records'
    },
    {
      label: 'Favorites',
      screen: 'screen.Favorites',
      icon: require('../images/NavigatorMenuIcon2.png'),
      selectedIcon: require('../images/NavigatorMenuIcon2.png'),
      title: 'Favorites'
    },
  ],
  drawer: {
    left: {
      screen: 'screen.Menu'
    },
  },
  passProps: {},

});
```

The `react-native-navigation` package does require a bit of Xcode configuration for iOS, including adding the native files of the dependency `react-native-controllers` to the Xcode project; and modifying the AppDelegate.m file... Though I'm unable to figure out why the startup configuration is effectively being ignored.

UPDATE:

I found a closed issue at react-native-navigation that explains how to use layouts for hybrid (tabbed/single page) apps: you simply start a new "app" instance. For example, in my app, I want the logout function to redirect to the Sign In screen.

This can be accomplished by calling a function that starts a new single screen app instance (Navigation.startSingleScreenApp). I tested this and confirm it works for LogOut. A similar solution can be employed for the sign in / start screens.

```js
  handleSignOut(props) {
    Meteor.logout(props);
    Navigation.startSingleScreenApp ({
      screen: {
        screen: 'screen.SignIn', // unique ID registered with Navigation.registerScreen
        navigatorStyle: {navBarHidden: true}, // override the navigator style for the screen, see "Styling the navigator" below (optional)
        navigatorButtons: {} // override the nav buttons for the screen, see "Adding buttons to the navigator" below (optional)
      },
    });
```

The issue persists on App startup, however, as the Navigation apps are loading as they're imported into the App/index file. Essentially, the if/else logic defining app state is being ignored.

Comment: Maybe the solution is to start the app as if the user is signed in, but use `Navigation.showModal()` to immediately popup the sign in screen. And when the user logs out, just show the sign in screen again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @KyleFinley - but on further scouring the library's git issues it appears that the suggested method for determining app state is by using redux. Still, there are a few folks who are requesting support via Meteor's state (per my question), so it appears to be a known issue. For our app, we'd like to use the state method so that the user doesn't need to log in each time they start the app.

Comment: I have tried using this method and to Navigation.startTabBasedApp after initial login is completed through screen displayd with Navigation.startSingleScreenApp, however my tabbed app does not show up even though it works fine by itself or if I do a refresh (I am cashing login state).